# Elementary number theory theorem may be related to some property of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ or $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, lie-groups

I know the following result in elementary number theory:

> If $a,b,c,d,m,n$ are integers such that $ad-bc=1$ and $mn\neq 0$, then
>   $$\gcd(am+bn,cm+dn)=\gcd(m,n).$$

The hypothesis $ad-bc=1$ seems too weird to not be related to some $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ or $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ property.

If we think of $\gcd$ as a function from $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, then this result means that the action of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ preserves the $\gcd$. Is there more to it?

Comment: Why do you need "and $mn \ne 0$" in the hypotheses? I don't think you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's it. It amounts to these two lemmas:

(I) $$ \gcd(-n,m) = \gcd(m,n) $$

(II) given $t \in \mathbb Z,$ we have
$$\gcd(m + tn,n) = \gcd(m,n) $$

Comment: I already proved it (in this same way). I just wanted to know if this is a disguized property of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro in a way it is. Given any integers $p,q,r,s$ with $(u,v) = (pm+qn, rm+sn)$ we have $\gcd(m,n) | \gcd(u,v).$ When the determinant $ps-qr $ is $\pm 1,$ we can use the inverse matrix to get $\gcd(u,v) | \gcd(m,n)$ as well, giving equality